Hibernate Envers: Error at Update Spring Boot 2.7 to Spring Boot 3.2
I have a working Application with Spring Boot 2.7 & Hibernate & Hibernate-Envers.
When I upgrade to Spring Boot 3.2 I get problems with Hibernate-Envers.
I get the following error:
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'auditConfiguration' defined in file [C:\Users\haglo\Documents\converted 3.2.2\main\main\target\classes\ch\genesis\configuration\AuditConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type 'jakarta.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

My code is:
@Configuration
@EnableJpaAuditing
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class AuditConfiguration {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    public AuditConfiguration(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        this.entityManagerFactory = entityManagerFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuditReader auditReader() {
        return AuditReaderFactory.get((Session) entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager());
    }
}

My pom.xml is:
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-envers</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
        <version>6.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>

I have migrated all from javax to jakarta.
